# What TPM2_GetCapability TPM_HT_LOADED_SESSION is intended to show?

Tags: linux, tpm, trusted-computing

Im trying to understand what is the intended output of [tpm2-tools/tpm2_getcap](https://github.com/tpm2-software/tpm2-tools/blob/master/man/tpm2_getcap.1.md) with the option of `handles-loaded-session`, the description says:

```
handles-loaded-session: Display handles about both loaded HMAC and policy sessions.
```

I understand that tpm2-tools perform `TPM2_ContextLoad` -> operation -> `TPM2_ContextSave` whenever it is possible. Therefore, `tpm2_getcap handles-saved-session` will show the saved context in TPM, check the following:

```
tpm2_startauthsession -S session.dat --policy-session
tpm2_policypcr -S session.dat -l "sha256:16"
tpm2_getcap handles-saved-session
    > 0x2000000
tpm2_flushcontext session.dat
tpm2_getcap handles-saved-session
    > nil
```

However, `tpm2_getcap handles-loaded-session` always returns nothing. So my question is in what situation `tpm2_getcap handles-loaded-session` will show any output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed. If a TPM2.0 Session is active, loaded in the TPM and in use, then you would see it in the list of TPM_HT_LOADED_SESSION.

Because the "tss2-software" stack stores the context in a file outside the TPM by default, then you would not see that session in loaded.

You would find it only in saved, when asking TPM2_GetCapability for TPM_HT_SAVED_SESSION as you did in your example.

Does this answer your question?

ps: Typically, context saving is needed when you have multiple users or applications working with the TPM. So, I am curious, is there a particular reason you want to use context saving or observe loaded sessions?

Comment: Im studying why the Linux Trusted Key fails with policy PCR. One reason is policy session is not being loaded correctly. You are absolutely right about the behavior of "tss2-software". But session will still not be loaded even I modify the tss2 to not perform context saving on exit. Later I observed that in Linux TPM driver itself is performing context load then save in every single call to TPM device node (/dev/tpm0 tpmrm0). I'll accept your answer since this behavior is well understood now.